# Insert data using checkbox into database

Tags: php, mysql

It seem's I cant insert data into my mysql database can you tell me what's wrong in my code?

```
<?
  include("header.php");
  $checkbox1 = $_POST['Cleared'];
  if($_POST['Submit']{
    foreach($_POST['checkbox1'] as $checkbox1)
      $query="INSERT INTO students (Library) VALUES ('$checkbox1')";
      mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Record is inserted";
  }
?>
```

here is the checkbox

```
$output .= '<form action = "librarysubmit.php" method="post">'.'<tr>'.'<td>'.$fname.' '.$lname.'
                <input type="checkbox" name="Cleared[]" value="1" style="position:absolute; right: 1000px;">
                '.'<input type="checkbox" name="NotCleared" value="0" style="position:absolute; right: 800px;">
                '.'</tr>'.'</td>'.'</form>';
```

Comment: I can see a comma after your `$query` as of now... than I can see that you are not closing your `if` condition so correct those typos first.. am amazed that PHP is not throwing you any errors

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: I dont have any errors and it doesn't insert into my database when i submit it

Comment: Please fix your typos. ie($query,)& $_POST["checkbox1"]

Comment: You have lot more errors within your code..

Comment: @davidstrachan i just updated it thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` statement is wrong.

Lose the `;` and add the ending `)`:

```
if($_POST['Submit']){
  ...
```

Make sure your submit form button is has `name='Submit'` too.

You also have `$_POST['checkbox1'] as $checbox1` but then later refer to `checkbox1` with the `k`.

Your form also needs this:

```
<input type='submit' name='Submit'>
```

if you want the `$_POST['Submit']` to work.

Comment: <form action = "librarysubmit.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name = "Submit" value = "Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>

Comment: Yes, but you also need a `type='checkbox'` with `name='checkbox1`. @maiko

Answer (score 0):

You also have a typo in

```
foreach($_POST["checkbox1"] as $checbox1)
```

There is no $checbox.

Comment: <form action = "librarysubmit.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name = "Submit" value = "Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>

Comment: What do you want to tell me?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
  include("header.php");  

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $checkbox = $_POST['cleared'];

    foreach($checkbox as $checked) {

      $query="INSERT INTO students (Library) VALUES ('$checked')";
      mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    }
    echo "Record is inserted";
  }
?>
```

But I suggest as mysql_query is deprecated to use mysqli instead or PDO.

Also I never would use capitals in my names or types in HTML.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `$query="INSERT INTO students (Library) VALUES ('$checked')";`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have variable like $_POST['checkbox1'] because there is no checkbox1 named checkbox in your html, also if a checkbox it's not ticked then its post variable will not exist.
I assume you have more than 1 checkboxes with the name "Cleared[]" and their values are different... otherwise there is no logic in the code.
Try this

```
<?
  include("header.php");
  $checkbox1 = $_POST['Cleared'];
  if( isset($_POST['Cleared']) ) {
    foreach($checkbox1 as $checbox1)
      $query="INSERT INTO students (Library) VALUES ('$checbox1')";
      mysql_query($query,) or die (mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Record is inserted";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This..

```
<?
include("header.php");
$checkbox1 = $_POST['Cleared'];
if($_POST['Submit']; {
 foreach($_POST["checkbox1"] as $checbox1)
  $query="INSERT INTO 'students' ('Library') VALUES ('$checkbox1')";
  mysql_query($query); or die (mysql_error());
 }
 echo "Record is inserted";
} 
?>
```

Comment: Did you really just suggest him to put a `;` behind an unfinished `IF` statement? + you misspelled `$checbox` in the foreach